# When is the expiry date?

Tags: food-safety, storage-method, food-science, food-preservation, drinks

[image: Coke Expiry Date]

Honest to god, I tried so hard to identify it. I do see `JAN 17` but I'm not sure if its January of 2017 or January the 17th. Plus I see 00:42 there but I'm not sure what it means, but I have a feeling its to do with its creation date.

I have checked on the internet however the Coke Date Expiry System on the cans have changed over time, found it very frustrating :D.

Thank you so much for your help.

PS. I've heard that its possible to drink a canned drink despite how old it is, is this true? That can't be true because in some way or form there is always some form of decay that grows in food/drinks.

Comment: Put enough rum in it and you should be fine.  Really it will taste OK or it will not.

Comment: Its okay to drink regular coke (ie sugar based) a little after the use by date. However, as a rule do not consume any diet sodas (or for that matter products that use artificial sweeteners) after the use by date.

Comment: Why would they need to get an expiration date down to the actual day? Even if it was the 17th, then where is the year? That should be more important. The bottom line is probably the production code.

Comment: Sorry, but if you can't tell it from the actual can, we can't tell it any better from a blurry photo. As for expiry dates vs. best by dates of food in general and soda in particular, we already have those covered in other questions.

Answer (score 1):

There is no expiration date.

At most, it would be a 'best buy' or 'sell by date'.

See http://www.fsis.usda.gov/wps/portal/fsis/topics/food-safety-education/get-answers/food-safety-fact-sheets/food-labeling/food-product-dating/food-product-dating